# Radio button not able to select

Tags: javascript, angular, radio-button

My `Script.js` file has below code

```
$scope.typeValue = ["120","123"];
```

My HTML has below code

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <!-- ng-change="RadioChange('type')"-->
        <input type="radio" name="type0" ng-value="true"/> {{typeValue[0]}}
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="type1" ng-value="false"/> {{typeValue[1]}}
    </label>
</div>
```

I cannot select radio button on my page

[image: page]

Answer (score 0):

I've ran this code locally and observed that radio button is selecting properly but unable to deselect once selected and also both are able to select.

Assuming your requirement is to select only one a time. If this is the scenario want to implement then the way to do is choose same name for the both radio inputs as:

```
<div class="radio">
<label>
 <!-- ng-change="RadioChange('type')"-->
<input type="radio" name="type" ng-value="true"/> {{typeValue[0]}}
 </label>
 <label>
<input type="radio" name="type" ng-value="false"/> {{typeValue[1]}}
</label>
</div>
```

If my assumption is wrong, requesting to elaborate your question properly if possible with example!

Comment: Hi prashant, Thanks for your time. I had tried using same names but I was not able to select any radio buttons. My requirement is I should be able to select any one out of two. But running my code locally two of the radio buttons are just dummy not able to select any. Is there any possibility for this?  And also I should be able to deselect and select other one!   Thanks in advance

Comment: could you post whole code to get an idea, where it is missing and what?

Comment: This piece of code works. When input tag is inside label it does not work. Kinda Weird.--------------------------- <div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="typeRadio1" ><label for="typeRadio1">{{typeValue[0]}}</label>
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="typeRadio2" ><label for="typeRadio2">{{typeValue[1]}}</label>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

At last hope, this is your requirement. Try this code... and let me know!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
        <!-- ng-change="RadioChange('type')"-->
          <input type="radio" name="type0" ng-value="true"/> {{typeValue[0]}}
        </label>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="type0" ng-value="false"/> {{typeValue[1]}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.typeValue = ["120","123"];
   });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: '<div class="radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="typeRadio1" name="optradio"  ng-model="typeValue[0].Selected" required><label for="typeRadio1">{{typeValue[0].Name}}</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="typeRadio2" name="optradio"  ng-model="typeValue[1].Selected" required><label for="typeRadio2">{{typeValue[1].Name}}</label>
                                    </div> '   this piece of code works